# How to get checkbox value in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I used Messier16.Forms.Controls.Checkbox to create checkbox for ios and andorid in Xamarin Forms.Now i am getting the checkbox but i cant read the  value either it is checked or not.Here is my code

Xaml file

```
 <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Start" Orientation="Horizontal">
 <cbox:Checkbox WidthRequest="45" VerticalOptions="Center"        CheckedChanged="MyCheckedMethod"/>
  <Label Text="Checkbox Example" VerticalOptions="Center" />

</StackLayout>
```

.cs File

```
     public void MyCheckedMethod(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       bool checked=e.checked;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the link https://github.com/messier16/Forms.Checkbox

```
cb1.CheckedChanged += 
    (sender, e) =>
    { 
        cb2.IsEnabled = e.IsChecked;
        cb3.Checked = !cb1.Checked;
    };
```

I think you will need `CheckedChangedEventArgs`, the class is provided in the link above.

```
public void MyCheckedMethod(object sender, CheckedChangedEventArgs e)
    {
       bool checked=e.IsChecked;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for Your response.I tired with that bool checked=e.IsChecked; But I am getting the following error  'EventArgs' does not contain a definition for 'IsChecked' and no extension method 'IsChecked' accepting a first argument of type 'EventArgs' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Have you added the `CheckedChangedEventArgs` class? You will also need the `Checkbox.cs` class. Have you installed the nuget package? I mean to say are you using it through nuget or direct code.

Comment: I added nuget package but i didnt added CheckedChangedEventArgs class and Checkbox.cs.If possible can you share the code.

Comment: Well then just install the package to all your platform specific code. And call `CheckboxRenderer.Init(); ` just after `Xamarin.Forms.Init();` in your respective applications and then use the code above in the answer. You won't need anything else.

Comment: I added **CheckboxRenderer.Init();** and changed my code  in .cs file         **Checkbox checknew = (Checkbox)sender;
                checkvalue = checknew.Checked;**
           Now it is working. Thank You very much